# Why do some fetishes use the suffix -philia, but others have -lagnia?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

I was interested to learn that ***hemophilia*** does not refer to the sexual fetish for blood, but a desiese. The fetish is called hemeotolagnia. This has me wondering, why do most words that refer to fetishes use the suffix -philia, but some use -lagnia?

Examples here:
*[English terms suffixed with -lagnia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_terms_suffixed_with_-lagnia)*

Is there a known etymological reason for this?

Comment: It's spelled *disease*

Answer (score 3):

***-philia*** and ***-lagnia*** are two suffixes both coming from Greek. They are used sometimes artificially, to coin new words. This was the case of ***hemophilia***:

> 1848 (also sometimes in Englished form hæmophily), ***from German hämophile, coined 1828 by German physician Johann Lucas Schönlein*** (1793-1864), from Greek haima "blood, bloodshed, streams of blood" (see -emia) + philia "to love" (see -philia), here with a sense of "tendency to."

***-philia*** is a

> word-forming element meaning "***friendship, fondness, tendency toward***," and in recent use "abnormal attraction to," from Greek philia "affection," from *philos* "loving," ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=-philia))

Note that the meaning *abnormal attraction to* is labelled as ***recent***.

As for *-lagnia* it was used to show exacerbated desire, lust, rather than simply love for something. For example:
***Algolagnia*** was coined in German in 1892 by German doctor and paranormalist Albert von Schrenck-Notzing (1862-1929) from Greek ***algos*** "pain" + ***lagneia*** "lust," from lagnein "to lust" and refers to fetishizing violence and pain out of lust ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=algolagnia&ref=searchbar_searchhint))

Note that ***algophilia*** is also used but with a slightly different meaning:

> a morbid pleasure in the pain either of oneself or of others.

So ***-lagnia*** is to ***-philia*** what ***lust*** is to ***pleasure***.

In your case, the word with -lagnia (which is [*hematolagnia*](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Hematolagnia) by the way, careful with your spelling) may have been coined in order to differentiate the psychological disorder from the organic disease (hemophilia), where *-philia* means *to have a tendency to*.

Comment: Wiktionary has a [list of -lagnia words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-lagnia#English) and a lot of them seem to have similar -philia terms e.g. urolagnia/urophilia, zoolagnia/zoophilia (maybe not something to search for at work). So in many cases you can use either.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, in many cases. The OP has found one of the few cases when the two words are differentiated in meaning through the suffixes.